# Respond to an event with given information

Tags: vb.net

I have two classes Receiver and Parser. Within parser class there is method called Run. Within this method are specific xml parse engine and on each of it step there could occur some error. Therefore if that situation happen i want to notyfy about error type and stop processing further. There is also Receiver class which is calling parser and subscribe to it's error event. What i want to do is - if Parser thrown error then at that moment event will be raised with information about error. Then Receiver class will be notified that error occur and depends on the error Receiver should send back custom information back to parser what to do and that's i dont know how to do - see comment within Receiver class :

> "SEND SPECIFIC INFORMATION TO CURRENT RUNNING PARSER - RUN METHOD WHAT
>   TO DO IN THIS CASE"

What i am thinking on that moment is to implement event also within Receiver class then Receiver based on select could fire this event and Parser could subscribe to it. But i am not sure if thinking correct.

Running from module:

```
 Dim aa As New Receiver
        aa.Go()
```

Receiver class:

```
Public Class Receiver

    Public WithEvents parser As New Parser

    Public Sub ParserDoJob(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As StartEventArgs) Handles parser.Start

        Dim error_type As ErrorT

        Select Case error_type
            Case e._error_type.OnlyMainNodeWithoutAnyFields

                'SEND SPECIFIC INFORMATION TO CURRENT RUNNING PARSER - RUN METHOD WHAT TO DO IN THIS CASE

            Case e._error_type.MoreFieldsThanSpecified


                'SEND SPECIFIC INFORMATION TO CURRENT RUNNING PARSER - RUN METHOD WHAT TO DO IN THIS CASE

            Case e._error_type.LessFieldsThanSpecified


                'SEND SPECIFIC INFORMATION TO CURRENT RUNNING PARSER - RUN METHOD WHAT TO DO IN THIS CASE

            Case Else

        End Select


    End Sub


    Public Sub Go()
        parser.Run()
    End Sub

End Class
```

Parser class:

```
Imports System.ComponentModel
Imports System.Xml

Public Class Parser




    Public Event Start(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As StartEventArgs)

    Protected Overridable Sub OnStart(ByVal e As StartEventArgs)
        RaiseEvent Start(Me, e)
    End Sub


    Public Sub Run()
...
 ElseIf FieldsFound_count = 0
                            OnStart(New StartEventArgs(ErrorT.OnlyMainNodeWithoutAnyFields))            

                        ElseIf dictionary_count < FieldsFound_count
                            OnStart(New StartEventArgs(ErrorT.MoreFieldsThanSpecified))     


                            found_error = True
                        ElseIf dictionary_count > FieldsFound_count
                            OnStart(New StartEventArgs(ErrorT.LessFieldsThanSpecified)) 
...
```

Custom event class:

```
Public Class StartEventArgs
    Inherits System.EventArgs

    Property _error_type As ErrorT

    Sub New(error_type As ErrorT)
        _error_type = error_type
    End Sub

End Class
```

Answer (score 0):

From your code, I don't see where `ParserDoJob` is getting called.  I might take a different approach though.  Since you're trying to handle possible errors, wrap your `parser.Run` in a Try/Catch block - which will catch specific exceptions that you'll define.  Then, in your `Parser` class, define methods you can call which will handle those exceptions.

```
Public Sub Go()
    Try
        parser.Run()
    Catch ex as OnlyMainNodeWithoutAnyFieldsException
        parser.HandleOnlyMainNodeWithoutAnyFields(.....)
    Catch ex2 as MoreFieldsThanSpecifiedException
        parser.HandleMoreFieldsThanSpecified(.....)
    Catch ex3 as LessFieldsThanSpecifiedException
        parser.HandleLessFieldsThanSpecified(.....)

End Sub
```

This is an example of an Exception class I use - renaming fields as they might be appropriate for you.

```
Public Class OnlyMainNodeWithoutAnyFieldsException
    Inherits Exception

    Public Sub New()
        MyBase.New()
    End Sub
    Public Sub New(ByVal parsingNode As String, ByVal innerException As Exception)
        MyBase.New(parsingNode, innerException)
    End Sub
    Protected Sub New(ByVal info As Runtime.Serialization.SerializationInfo, ByVal context As Runtime.Serialization.StreamingContext)
        MyBase.New(info, context)
    End Sub
End Class
```

Comment: what do you mean you dont see. It will be called every tim when for instance this will be riched : OnStart(New StartEventArgs(ErrorT.OnlyMainNodeWithoutAnyFields)) within Run method